# How to convert day of year and year to a standard date format

Tags: r, date

I have a list of day-of-years (1-365) and years (ex:2012-2015). How would I convert the date from this list?

I tried the as.Date(x, origin = "2012-01-01") but that only works for the first year as for year 2013, it repeats from days 1-365 again for the other years.

Sample:

```
days <- c(262,263,264)
years <- c(2017,2017,2017)
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your list using this `dput(head(list))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the origin based on the year you have in your list e.g.:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(dayyear = c(1, 100, 300, 1), year = c(2013,2013,2013, 2014))
df$origin <- as.Date(paste0(df$year, "-01-01"),tz = "UTC") - days(1)
as.Date(df$dayyear, origin = df$origin, tz = "UTC") 

[1] "2013-01-01" "2013-04-10" "2013-10-27" "2014-01-01"
```